# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Window1.exe

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I started getting this exception just today and i'm suffering with its fix. I'm wondering how to do it because I didn't find other answers helpful. I have these two parts of the code, It looks like my code is being cycled but I don't know how to fix that.

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        //Produkt produkt = new Produkt("e", 12, 21, 1);
        string[] header = { "-----------------------------------------------------------", "            Pokus o pokladni software na MVOP", "        Asi to odevzdam pozdeji, protoze jsem nemel cas", "            Jo a taky neumim poradne programovat", "                takze jestli projdu ", "                TAK TO BUDE ZAZRAK", "-----------------------------------------------------------" };
        int pocet = 1;
        public double total = 0;
        string RegisteredUser = "test";
        public string cas = "now";
        DateTime zacatekObjednavky;
        TimeSpan casObjednavky;
        Window1 win2 = new Window1();
        Platba platba = new Platba();
        public double totalDPH;


        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            NovaObjednavka();
            DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
            timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
            timer.Start();
            zacatekObjednavky = DateTime.Now;
        }
```

```
  public partial class Platba : Window
    {
        double totalPlatba;
        double totalPuvodni;
        double zbytek;
        MainWindow Form;


        public Platba()
        {
            Form = new MainWindow();
            totalPuvodni = Form.total;
            InitializeComponent();
            totalPlatba = Form.total;
        }
```

But the weird thing about this is the fact that it Crashes the third window, that has nothing to do with the cycled forms, so I'm kinda confused.

```
  public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        int idUzivatele;
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-use-the-call-stack-window?view=vs-2019

Comment: MainWindow creates a Platba and a Window1, Platba creates a Mainwindow1, MinWindow1 creates a Platba and a Window1 and so on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Gusman has pointed out, you have a recursive call structure.  @mjwills suggests reading how the stack trace works.  The stack keeps track of function calls so they know where to return when they're done.  It will show you the sequence of function calls.

Also, it would be helpful to learn how to step through your code rather than simply run it.  You will see the sequence of the initialization routines and constructors and it will become apparent where your problems are.  Use the Debug menu and start your project with "Step Into" instead of "Start Debugging."

In your case, specifically, your Platba constructor has a call to `Form = new MainWindow();`.  That's most likely not what you want.  Instead, you may want to pass the MainWindow to the Platba constructor as a parameter.  E.g. `Platba platba = Platba(this);`

```
    public Platba(MainWindow mainWindow)
    {
        Form = new MainWindow();
        totalPuvodni = mainWindow.total;
        InitializeComponent();
        totalPlatba = mainWindow.total;
    }
```

Also, change the MainWindow constructor to initialize the Platba and other windows.

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        platba = new Platba(this);
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: Well I'm quite aware whats wrong, but don't know how to fix it, cause i need to call these in other windows.

Comment: I can't tell you how to fix it, because I can't divine what you want to do.  I've updated the answer to point you in one direction.  Most likely you don't want the MainWindow creating a Platba and then having the Platba creating a MainWindow.  Take the MainWindow new constructor out of the Platba constructor.

Comment: I need to use several variables from the forms between them, so I need them to be called somehow, for example I need the total variable in Platba window and I'm using several components from Platba in MainWindow, so I need it called somehow like this

Comment: Change the Platba constrructor to take the main form:`Platba(MainWindow mainWindow)`